# Lambda canary deployment with CodePipeline (CodeBuild + CodeDeploy)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to figure out how to build a CodePipeline that would do a canary deployment of a Lambda. I have a working CodeBuild project that creates a Lambda zip file in S3 when a commit is made into the master branch of a CodeCommit repo. Similarly, I've created the necessary Lambda alias and CodeDeploy application and I can manually edit the Lambda, publish a new version, create the necessary `appspec.yml` and start a new deployment. All of this works.

My problem is how to fit these two together. I have a CodePipeline, which first runs the CodeBuild step and this works just fine. However, it fails when it reaches the CodeDeploy stage, because there is now `appspec.yml`. It's not clear to me how the `appspec.yml` should be created. The file looks something like:

```
version: 0.0
Resources:
  - myLambdaFunction:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
      Properties:
        Name: "testlambda"
        Alias: "testlambdaalias"
        CurrentVersion: "1"
        TargetVersion: "2"
```

If I generate the file dynamically, then I would need to pull the current version of the Lambda as well as the target version. I could write a Python script with Boto3 that publishes the Lambda and pulls the current version of out of the alias. However, my understanding is that CodePipeline generates a zip of the previous step. How am I supposed to provide the `appspec.yml` file to the CodeDeploy step? Is there a built-in way to create the right function versions? Is there a built-in way of generating the `appspec.yml` file without resorting to your own scripts?

Comment: Have you considered using CloudFormation or SAM? SAM has support for deploying a lambda with a canary deployment.

Comment: We have already standardized everything on top of Terraform and don't want to bring in additional tooling. However, it looks like there is no solution to my problem without involving something external. I decided to drop CodeDeploy and wrote my own Lambdas that accomplish the same task.

Comment: I wouldn't say there aren't options, just that if you can use what is there it makes it easier. I would look into what SAM creates automatically, and see if you can replicate that in Terraform. Keep in mind that SAM is just a preprocessor for CloudFormation, so you should be able to create the same results in any tool.